# SFDX: Create a softphone layout with SFDX

Tags: salesforcedx, softphone

Is there any way to create a Softphone Layout via SFDX? I have not found any command that explicitly explains how to do it. Any JSON configuration maybe?

In case it is not yet supported, does anybody know if sfdc plans to implement it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SoftPhone layouts [aren't supported](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_unsupported_types.htm) by the metadata api and can only be created manually in an org. There isn't a command to create one. That would have to be done manually (or through some sort of browser automation) after the scratch org is created.